# Multiply certain columns in a dataframe without removing other existing columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to create a new data frame in Python (pandas) that keeps all of the existing columns in my DataFrame whilst multiplying only certain columns by 100,000.

The code I am using is:

```
df[['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6']].multiply(100000)
```

This code keeps the columns of t1-t6 however deletes everything else. (about 10 other columns) Is there a way to keep my other existing columns while running this code?

Comment: `df.update(df[['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6']].multiply(100000))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many options

1. Assign back to specified columns:

```
df[['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']] = \
    df[['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']].multiply(100000)
```

2. [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) + `multiply`:

```
df.loc[:, ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']] = \
    df[['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']].multiply(100000)
```

3. `*=`:

```
df[['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']] *= 100000
```

4. [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) + `*=`:

```
df.loc[:, ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']] *= 100000
```

5. [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas-dataframe-update):

```
df.update(df[['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']].multiply(100000))
```

Test frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    't1': {0: 1}, 't2': {0: 2}, 't3': {0: 3}, 't4': {0: 4}, 't5': {0: 5},
    't6': {0: 6}, 't7': {0: 7}, 't8': {0: 8}, 't9': {0: 9}, 't10': {0: 10},
    't11': {0: 11}
})
```

Output:

```
       t1      t2      t3      t4      t5      t6  t7  t8  t9  t10  t11
0  100000  200000  300000  400000  500000  600000   7   8   9   10   11
```

---

Timing information via perfplot:

[image: benchmarking perfplot]

| Fastest |  |  | Slowest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Direct assignment or *= | Using `loc` | `update` | for loop + map |
| 1,3 | 2,4 | 5 | [@YoungMin Park's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67680886/15497888) |

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot


def gen_data(n):
    return pd.DataFrame({f't{i}': np.arange(0, n) for i in range(1, 12)})


def assign_back_multiply(df):
    df[['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']] = \
        df[['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']].multiply(100000)
    return df


def assign_back_with_loc_multiply(df):
    df.loc[:, ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']] = \
        df[['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']].multiply(100000)
    return df


def times_equals(df):
    df[['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']] *= 100000
    return df


def times_equals_with_loc(df):
    df.loc[:, ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']] *= 100000
    return df


def df_update(df):
    df.update(df[['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']].multiply(100000))
    return df


# @YoungMin Park's Answer
def for_loop_map(df):
    target_columns = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']
    for one_column in target_columns:
        df[one_column] = df[one_column].map(lambda x: x * 100000)
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    out = perfplot.bench(
        setup=gen_data,
        kernels=[
            assign_back_multiply,
            assign_back_with_loc_multiply,
            times_equals,
            times_equals_with_loc,
            df_update,
            for_loop_map
        ],
        labels=[
            'assign_back_multiply',
            'assign_back_with_loc_multiply',
            'times_equals',
            'times_equals_with_loc',
            'df_update',
            'for_loop_map @YoungMin Park'
        ],
        n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
        equality_check=None
    )
    out.save('perfplot_results.png', transparent=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use `map()` with the information of `target columns` which you want to process

```
import pandas as pd

d={'t1':[2,3,1,4,5],
   't2':[5,4,3,2,1],
   'other1':[1,9,9,8,7],
   'other2':[3,3,4,5,6]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

[image]

```
target_columns=['t1','t2']
for one_column in target_columns:
  df[one_column]=df[one_column].map(lambda x:x*100000)
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I've added your solution to my perfplot in case you're curious about how your solution scales.